# REMOVE LOCK SCREEN SAMSUNG Android 8.0

Tags: samsung

Hello my friends I open the system.img by HXD and remove the locksettings.db but with Android 8.0 the phone hang on the Samsung logo Is it a solution to bypass the lock please

Comment: Who told you to remove settings.db ?

Comment: I don't think this method works on Oreo and higher because android has new security checks mechanisms that's why the phone hang on booting logo

Comment: My friend i trying on more than method and deleting system ui but I have a problem ,, the device standing on the Samsung logo and not turning on
I want the method to bypass or deleting lock screen without wiping data on the Oreo version thank you

Comment: At this point, your only option is to flash the device and this will reset the device to the  factory settings

Comment: Thank you again I do not want to wipe the data but I want to bypass the pattern only and I'll let you know that the solution is available but I'm looking for it

Comment: I'll appreciate it. Please share with us once you found a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

Any modifications to your system will cause a boot loop... What you are seeing "logo"  ...

You need to flash that stock system.img without the modifications and then you need to log in to the account associated with the device..

If you've forgotten the account details, Use a computer to do the recovery process.. And then use the new details to log in.